# How do I prevent the destroying of all instances of an object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, instance-variables

I have a prefab object called Beam, which contains several things but one is an object that when an instance of it is collided with and triggered, should destroy itself.

Currently, I have the script that generates all of the instances on a variable called Beams. Shown here:

[image]

When that runs, it creates clones within it. Seen here:

[image]

You will also see in the last image, the Beam prefab that contains the Cookie in it. That cookie is where I have a script that says, if I hit it, destroy. That code looks like this:

```
...

public class Collectibles : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameManager game;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        game = FindObjectOfType<GameManager> ();
    }

    ...

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if(other.tag == "Player"){
            string coinType = "Cookie";
            game.AddCollectible(coinType);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }


    }
}
```

Currently, when I run into a cookie, it runs Destroy(gameObject) and destroys ALL instances of the cookie (one per each Clone).

This code lives on Cookie, not on Beams. Is that correct? Should I have the code somewhere else? I also tried Destroy(this) but that doesn't do what I thought it would do (just the instance).

Is it possible that from where I was calling Destroy, the script doesn't have access to the instances, or am I missing something? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are all your cookies in different positions so that you're not entering all of their colliders simultaneously?

Comment: Yes definitely in different positions.

Comment: Could you show the Inspector for an object that you have your `Collectibles` script attached to

Comment: Is your `Collectibles` script attached to your "Cookie" Gameobject or to "collectibles" object? If the `collectibles` script is attached to your "Collectibles" gameobject it will delete that gameobject, along with all its children. If you *just* want to delete the cookie you've hit the collider of you need to attach the `Collectibles` script to the "Cookie" gameobject

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want that when the "player" collides with an instance of "beam" only destroy the instance of Cookie (or the gameobject that contains the script), in this case it would do so with the tag:

```
public GameObject[] arrayofcookie;

public int destroyedinstances=1; 
//this int will tell how many instances you want to be destroyed (from the last instantiated to the first)

//for this example the last instance will be deleted


public void destroyCookie()
{
    arrayofcookie= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cookie");
    for (int i = 0; i < destroyedinstances; i++)
    {
        Destroy(arrayofcookie[i].gameObject);
    }
}
```

You call this method in the cookie script, in the collider or if you prefer with an invoke method after N seconds.

I do not think I have understood your question very well, but in these problems I prefer to use the label and it also depends on the nature of your game

Comment: Make sure the object has the Cookie label

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants, this will also destroy *all* instances of the gameObject with the "Cookie" tag, instead of just the one collided with. OP correct me if i'm wrong though.

Comment: yes, you are correct, I misunderstood the question, in that case it would be the same but without using the cycle:

Comment: public void destroyCookie()
{
    
    
        Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cookie"));
    
}

Comment: The usefulness of the arrangement is that you can destroy only some objects, for example the last two instances:

Comment: public GameObject[] arrayofcookie;

public void destroyCookie()
{
    arrayofcookie= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cookie");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Destroy(arrayofcookie[i].gameObject);
    }
}

Comment: You can edit new information into your original answer by clicking the "edit" button underneath it- this helps in keeping the information focused and easy to find!